# Getting mini pages right

Tags: spacing, minipage

I would like to print out two minipages of equal size next to each other but not exceeding over the limits of the page what it does right now. I don't understand why it happens and I already had some trouble in getting all the lines left-adjusted (I guess, I didn't find the best solution.)

Thanks for you help.

```
\documentclass[9pt,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage[margin=0mm,top=10mm]{geometry} %geometry
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
&\textbf{Elasticity}\\
&\epsilon(f,x) =\frac{df/f}{dx/x}=\frac{df}{dx}*\frac{x}{f}=f'*\frac{x}{f}\\
&\text{If x is changed by 1\%...?}\\
&=\frac{1}{y}*f'*x\\
&=\frac{d \ln (y)}{y}*\frac{dy}{dx}*\frac{dx}{d \ln (x)}=\frac{d \ln (y)}{d 
\ln (x)} \text{\underline{log. derivation}}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
&\textbf{Newton}\\
&T(x)=f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)\\
&0=f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)=f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)~~~x=\frac{f'(a)a-f(a)}{f'(a)}=a- 
\frac{f(a)}{f'(a)}\\
&\text{Points given by }x_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{f(a_n)} 
{f'(a_n)}
\end{align*}\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One problem is `margin=0mm`, change that into, e.g., `left=0mm`. Another problem is that the equations on the right are too wide to fit in the minipage, introduce a linebreak before `x=` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\noindent` before the first `minipage` and `%` between the `minipage`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt,fleqn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=0mm,top=10mm]{geometry} %geometry

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{align*}
    &\textbf{Elasticity} \\
    &\epsilon(f, x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}f/f}{\mathrm{d}x/x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} \times \frac{x}{f} = f' \times \frac{x}{f} \\
    &\text{If x is changed by 1\%\ldots ?}\\
    &= \frac{1}{y} \times f' \times x \\
    &= \frac{\mathrm{d} \ln (y)}{y} \times \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \times \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\ln (x)} 
      = \frac{\mathrm{d}\ln (y)}{\mathrm{d}\ln (x)} \text{\underline{log. derivation}}
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{align*}
    &\textbf{Newton} \\
    &T(x) = f'(a)(x - a) + f(a) \\
    & 0 = f'(a)(x - a) + f(a) = f'(a)(x - a) + f(a) \\
    & x = \frac{f'(a) a - f(a)}{f'(a)} = a - \frac{f(a)}{f'(a)}\\
    &\text{Points given by }x_{n + 1} = a_n - \frac{f(a_n)}{f'(a_n)}
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ...I did change the layout of the right-hand `minipage` slightly.

Comment: Thank you very much! It does not only work but the code also looks better now!